# Selecting the highest ID number in an SQL stored proc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

I am writing a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
SELECT Replace(c_invoice, Char(13) + Char(10), ''),
       c_uom1,
       c_uom2
FROM   @invoice_TABLE AS invoice
       INNER JOIN @uom1_TABLE AS uom1
               ON invoice.ID = uom1.ID
       INNER JOIN @uom2_TABLE AS uom2
               ON uom1.ID = uom2.ID
WHERE  uom1.ID = 4
```

But I would like the WHERE clause to use the highest uom1.ID number - can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT replace(c_invoice,char(13) + char(10), ''), c_uom1, c_uom2 
    FROM @invoice_TABLE AS invoice
    INNER JOIN @uom1_TABLE as uom1 ON invoice.ID = uom1.ID
    INNER JOIN @uom2_TABLE as uom2 ON uom1.ID = uom2.ID
    WHERE uom1.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @uom1_TABLE)
```

Comment: @LYKS: Did you show a WHOLE query. There is no GROUP BY part in the original query.

Comment: thank you so much this worked! =)

I actually corrected some parts of my code and added this code and it worked. Thank you so much Valex :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `WHERE` you can use `TOP  WITH TIES... ORDER BY`

```
SELECT TOP (1)  WITH TIES replace(c_invoice, char(13) + char(10), ''),
               c_uom1,
               c_uom2
FROM   @invoice_TABLE AS invoice
       INNER JOIN @uom1_TABLE AS uom1
         ON invoice.ID = uom1.ID
       INNER JOIN @uom2_TABLE AS uom2
         ON uom1.ID = uom2.ID
ORDER  BY uom1.ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT replace(c_invoice,char(13) + char(10), ''), c_uom1, c_uom2 FROM @invoice_TABLE AS invoice
    INNER JOIN (select MAX(ID) AS ID FROM @uom1_TABLE) as uom1 ON invoice.ID = uom1.ID
    INNER JOIN @uom2_TABLE as uom2 ON uom1.ID = uom2.ID
```